# What anime is this dakimakura from?

Tags: uta-kata

[image]

I was wondering what anime is that girl on dakimakura from? The screenshot is from NCIS series, season 9 episode 21. She's similar to Wendy form Fairy Tail, but have different eye color. I'm curious!

Comment: I wouldn't be _too_ surprised if the creators based the design of this character off of a bunch of anime girls (for the reasons similar to why we see "Dawd Ostrakh" instead of "David Oistrakh" in Madoka Magica). Great question though!

Comment: i'm curious which episode of NCIS this is and if Tony makes any comment about the pillow (i can see him doing it)

Comment: @Memor-X: the OP stated which episode and season this was from...

Comment: @Maroon oh! i didn't see that \*facepalm\*

Comment: Tony said that this girl is kinda hot :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bootleg version of **Manatsu Kuroki** from the anime [**Uta Kata**](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=2481)

[image]

Comment: Oh well... hmm I don't think so that they look similar :). The hair color should be darker and more blue.

Comment: That's like saying [**this**](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNTk1/z/ODkAAMXQrNtRzzRo/$(KGrHqF,!ncFHLO8dTw3BRzzRn)1D!~~60_35.JPG) isn't *Doraemon* because it should be blue and not red. It's most likely a *China-quality* dakimakura using an "original" colour palette.

Comment: Okay Okay you got me... xD. Well if you ignore the colors it is actully a pretty good guess I have to say. If you extend your answer where you say so or **even better** you find a source where the color change is stated, I would say that your answer could be right :o.